# What is more efficient?: Many small CDSs or one huge CDS with many "NaN" values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, plot, bokeh

I am developing an Bokeh Server Application.

I would like to plot 10-15 plots with 10 glyphs each one, at least. So I need some `ColumnDataSource` (CDS) with different sizes. I have checked that if I use many CDS, the bokeh server **becomes unstable**. So I had to reduce the number of CDSs.

I need to use at least 4 CDSs in the application:

- CDS for points - 2500 values - main data, three point glyphs per plot
- CDS for multilines (profiles) - few values, three lists of points per profile, six profiles per plot
- CDS for profile circles - the same points as the multiline profiles, but I could use a `CDSView` here with filters
- CDS for datatable - 10-20 values, two columns, to show the selected sample

#### Questions

- Which is the limit number of CDS I should use?
- Instead of many CDSs I could add many columns to the main CDS (2400 rows), but if I do this I had to fill each column with many `NaN` values (`2400 - N` values, where `N` is about 10-20). Is this the most efficient way to do this?